# rsync - omit top-level dir time

Tags: rsync

I would like to

```
rsync -avh /usr/local/ remote:/usr/local/
```

and got

```
rsync: failed to set times on "/usr/local/.": Permission denied (13)
./
```

Could I sync dir time for subdirs but not for the top dir?

I am on macOS and /usr/local is protected by SIP, so `sudo` won't work either.

Comment: Apart from the actual error message, there are no issues, right?

Comment: @Kusalananda : lots of items will be rsync-ed and finally it prints "some files/attrs were not transferred". I can't make sure whether '/usr/local' timestamp is the only error.

(Separating stderr from stdout might work. I am looking for a better solution.)